# how get month of week number and year

Tags: mysql

I need to return the month number, from the 1st day of the week number

I have a function in mySQL, but some results do not work well

```
CREATE FUNCTION `MonthOfWeek`( pyear YEAR, pweek SMALLINT, pday SMALLINT ) RETURNS smallint(6)
BEGIN
  DECLARE vdate DATE;
  DECLARE vday SMALLINT;
  SET vdate = AddDate(Concat( pyear, '-01-01'), 7*pweek );
  SET vday = DayOfWeek( vdate );
  SET vdate = IF( vday = 1, vdate, AddDate( vdate, 1-vday ));
  RETURN Month( vdate );
END$$
```

https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2021

date 4.4.2021 = year 2021 and week 13 = month 3.

date 2.2.2021 = year 2021 week 5 = month 2. Function return 1 :(

thanks

Comment: *date 4.4.2021* There is no DATE datatype variable in fn parameters. Be more precise.

Comment: What are you calling first day of week ,sunday or monday?

Comment: furst day is monday

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MONTH('2021-04-04' - INTERVAL WEEKDAY('2021-04-04') DAY) x;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
|    3 |
+------+

SELECT MONTH('2021-02-02' - INTERVAL WEEKDAY('2021-02-02') DAY)x;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
|    2 |  -- :-)
+------+
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.